# Action Filter Unable To Block An Unauthorized Request in Controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to block a request in controller if it doesn't have a specific value in header. So I did the following using some guidelines:

```
public class InvalidTokenAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var Authorization = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["test"];

        if (Authorization != "12345678910")
        {
            context.ModelState.AddModelError("Authorization", "Authorization failed!");
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

It worked and confirmed when I use the attribute in a specific controller putting  **Console.WriteLine()** in the custom attribute class. But unfortunately it doesn't throw any exception in the controller level. I did something as follows:

**Request**:

```
GET http://localhost:PortNo/WeatherForecast/GetAllTeams
test: "12345678"
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
[InvalidToken]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamDetails>>> GetAllTeams()
{
    string Token = Request.Headers["test"];
  
    return Ok(Token);
}
```

With the attribute, it shouldn't get into the controller as the header value is invalid or mismatched. Unfortunately value returned in the controller and shows output. Is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Authorization != "12345678910"` , your action filter just add a ModelError, it will not Interrupt request . So ,If you don’t want it get into the controller,you can add some code like：

**Filter**

```
public class InvalidTokenAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var Authorization = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["test"];

        if (Authorization != "12345678910")
        {
            context.ModelState.AddModelError("Authorization", "Authorization failed!");
            //you can add this code to Interrupt request,So request will not get into controller
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly @Xinran Shen. Thanks a lot but when there's a valid header value, it throws the same exception. Though it shouldn't, right?

Comment: @user8512043 When there's an unvalid header,it throws an exception , It response `400`code in postman . but when there's a valid header value , request will get into the action,because the code  `return Ok(Token)` in your `GetAllTeams()` action,so the action will return the `token`,it is not an exception,you can see it response `200` code in postman.

Comment: Ok. When there's a valid token, it still shows the same message. See this - https://ibb.co/Y4gmK31. Using vs code and rest client app to test the api.

Comment: HI.can you get the value of `Authorization ` in `var Authorization =context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["test"]` when you send request with a valid header value?

Comment: Yes, getting it perfectly - https://ibb.co/L9x9Dkt. I can see in your case, it works with Postman,

Comment: So. when you send request with `test=12345678910`, `Authorization` Also equals to `12345678910` ,right?

Comment: Yes, both are equal.

Comment: The next step is `if (Authorization != "12345678910"){......}`,So when `Authorization=12345678910`, `Authorization ` will not get into the `if{..}`,it will get into the `GetAllTeams()` directly and return `Token`, It may be something wrong in your `if(...)`

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way that I can make it work for the time being?

Comment: This method is simple and fast. I personally tested this method and it succeeded. I suggest you use `postman` to send the request and try again.

Comment: I got the issue. When the header value is passed to the filter, it turns into this for some reason `"\"12345678910\""`. So when I matched this thing, it worked. Could you write what could be the reason for this?

Comment: when you send request in `rest-api` just send `GET http://localhost:PortNo/WeatherForecast/GetAllTeams
test: 12345678` , don't add `""`.